# Outlook archive like Gmail

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

How can I make Outlook more like Gmail? I would like to 'archive' conversations so they don't appear in my inbox, but I can still search them.

Outlook version? It doesn't have 'help / about' like other programs, but it says 'Version 14' elsewhere.

My email account is on an Microsoft Exchange server

Comment: What version of Outlook?

Comment: If you don't want items in your Inbox, move them to folders. If you mean that you want them out of your current PST file, that's a completely different discussion, but it's certainly not clear from your question.

Comment: This solution will require you to run a macro and it will archive all the mails from the inbox: [http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/outlook-2010-move-message-to-folder-after-message/e7f1acac-bb78-4e03-84da-9cab463e64f4](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/outlook-2010-move-message-to-folder-after-message/e7f1acac-bb78-4e03-84da-9cab463e64f4)

Comment: Version 14 is Office 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a 'quick step' that moves a conversation to a folder called 'archive'.

Massive caveat: one can't undo quick steps, a bug in Outlook.

Comment: The quick step is only half the gmail desire though (from my point of view, CP didn't specifically ask for this..)  with Gmail, a new message on a previously archived thread brings the whole thread back to the inbox.  Sadly I can't find a way to do this with a second quick step nor an inbox rule as they don't understand the "conversation" server side as Outlook does client side.

Answer (score 0):

Is Gmail your email server for the account? Gmail supports archiving behavior in Outlook through IMAP. See [this article](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=77657&topic=1668961&ctx=topic).